# Record and Save Audio in One Activity and Play back Audio in Another Activity

Tags: android, parameter-passing, audio-recording, android-audiomanager, audio-player

In my App with many activities, I am trying to make a recording in one activity and store it in the phone files.  Then in another activity, I want to play that file back.  I think I may have a problem with with how I am saving the original file because it crashes on the second activity when it wants to read the file.  I am not sure how to save in one activity and then read that audio file in the next activity.  I have included what I thought was relevant code from both activities.

```
//This is the Activity that simply records and then saves the audio file

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        createTempFile("Status_Recorder.txt", "INPROGRESS");

         /*
          * Create the file where the audio tone that is recorded will be saved
          *
          */
        try{
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("audio_test_right.3gp" , MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exit_function();
        }

        path = mContext.getFilesDir()+"/audio_test_right.3gp";

        start_recording();
}


    //Method to Start the Recording
    private void start_recording() {
        //Intialize the recorder
        try{
        speaker_recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        speaker_recorder.reset();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(log_tag,"Recorder Initialization Failed");
            createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
        }

        //Setting for the Recorder
        try{
        Log.i(log_tag,"Setting the recorder");
        speaker_recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        speaker_recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        speaker_recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        speaker_recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(log_tag,"Recording Settings Failed");
            createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
        }
        //Prepare the Recorder
        try{
            Log.i(log_tag,"Preparing the Recorder");
            speaker_recorder.prepare();
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(log_tag,"Recording failed");
            createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
            exit_function();
        }

        //Start the Recorder
        try {
            Log.i(log_tag,"Starting the recorder");
            title_text = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView));
            title_text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            title_text.setText("RECORDING");
            speaker_recorder.start();
//            Thread.sleep(10000);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createTempFile("Status_Recorder.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
                    exit_function();
                }
            }, timer);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(log_tag,"Recorder start failed");
            createTempFile("Status.txt", "COMPLETED-RECORDER FAILED");
            exit_function();
        }

}

    private void exit_function() {
        if (speaker_recorder != null) {
            speaker_recorder.release();
        }
        onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onDestroy()
     * Function invoked before we exit the application . Reset all the volume
     * and stream values in this function
     */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(log_tag,"Entered onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
        this.finish();

    }

    /*
     * Function to create the a text file in the application directory context. This function
     * takes the file name and the string that is to be written in it as the input. This function is invoked
     * to create the Result.txt file.
     */
    private void createTempFile(String filename, String text) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename , MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            osw.write(text);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

//This is the Second Activity, but it Crashes when it gets to the mp.setDataSource(path); because I guess it cant find the path

```
 private void playSound(boolean speakers) {
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
//        audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
        path = mContext.getFilesDir() + "/audio_test_right.3gp";
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (speakers) {
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        } else {
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);

        }
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                createTempFile("Status_RightSpeaker.txt", "COMPLETED");
                exit_function();
            }
        });
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i have a working code for your question

This method when supplied with `true` will **start** recording else it will **stop** recording. So you can do this on your first activity

```
private void startOrStopRecording(boolean record){
    if (record) {
        // Record the audio
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_test.3gp");

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }else{
        // Stop recording
        if (mMediaRecorder != null){
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This method when supplied with `true` starts to **play** the sound else **stop**. So you can implement it on your Second Activity

NOTE `String mFile = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/audio_test.3gp";`

```
private  void playOrStop(boolean play){
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try{
        if (play){
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFile);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        }else {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Mtali", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Be sure to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

**B.O.N.U.S**

You can use `ToggleButton` to

**START & STOP RECORDING**

JAVA

```
final ToggleButton recordButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.record_button);
recordButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        startOrStopRecording(isChecked);
    }
});
```

XML

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/record_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="@string/start_playback_string"
    android:textOn="@string/stop_playback_string"/>
```

**START AND STOP PLAYING**

JAVA

```
ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        playOrStop(isChecked);
    }
});
```

XML

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textOff="@string/start_playback_string"
        android:textOn="@string/stop_playback_string"/>
```

Comment: You are amazing!!! I am trying to stumble my way through this Android stuff and you keep saving my life.  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: in 2019, I'm getting an error that setAudioSource has failed for this line: 
 
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);       @Emmanuel Mtali any ideas? I have permissions set in the manifest so it's not that.